# unsure of the best data type to use

Tags: arrays, vb.net

I am creating a Sudoku project in vb.net, to such an end I need to store a list of all the possibilities for each square where the squares are indexed by one number. for example the computer needs to know that for square [8] the numbers {1,3,5,9} are possible etc... I began by using a jagged array however there is no apparent 'remove' method which needs to be called a lot. this makes my code looks ugly with all the redim statements in it and so I was curious as to whether a list or arraylist would be best suited to my purposes? I have discovered arraylists have a remove method but I have also read that array lists are all but deprecated and i want to know if there is a nicer solution to this.

Comment: consider using a List, presumably List(of Integer)

Comment: ArrayList is "deprecated" in favour of generic `List(of T)`. In your case you could use a `List(of List(of Integer))`.

Comment: {1,3,5,9} is a set.  Use HashSet(Of Integer).